# Disable the Research Task Pane in Excel/Office

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-office-2003

Can how I disable the Research Task Pane in Microsoft Excel/Office 2003?

Answer (score 10):

I have fought with this myself for years, but I finally found the answer:

1. From Word, press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F11</kbd> to open the VBA Editor.
2. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>G</kbd> to open the Immediate Window.
3. Type this line and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>:

   ```
   Application.CommandBars("Research").Enabled = False
   ```

Answer (score 3):

Turns off the Research Pane/Pain:

Go to   `Add/Remove Programs ---> Microsoft Office ---> Add or Remove Features ---> expand Office Tools ---> disable Research Explorer Bar` (there's a red X which you select to disable it.

Worked for me and I was delighted to get rid of the damned thing.

As I understand it you can still access the Research Pane manually (e.g. clicking on its icon). I have not bothered with this to manual access to check it out because I'm hoping to never see this pane again.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean to stop the task pane from appearing at Excell startup or disable it altogether?

If you want to disable it, I can't help you, sorry, but if you want it to stop appearing go to "Tools", "Options" menu, then in the View tab, and uncheck "Startup Task Pane."

If it doesn't works, have a look at http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000753.htm; I'm told you may have to manually edit the registry in some cases. 
(Danger, Will Robinson!)

Answer (score 0):

You can't disable it. You can only remove all the services it tries to use then keep closing it. It comes up from various key combinations like Ctrl+Whatever or Alt+Whatever.

Answer (score 0):

Try disabling it by disabling the Bing bar on your browser. That was the only thing I changed and it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can just try Alt+click on any cell and then go to Review tab and uncheck research button. You will see the pane doesn't automatically show up any more.